# DeviseTokenAuth in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise-token-auth

I am implementing a session in my Rails Application, and I'm using `DeviseTokenAuth` gem.
I want to implement a scenario that If a user does not send a request from the Front-end in 15 minutes, then the session should expire; The session is valid for 15 minutes. However, if a user is sending requests continuously, the session time should be extended for the next 15 minutes. I am sharing my `DeviseTokenAuth` configuration code.

```rb
DeviseTokenAuth.setup do |config|

  config.change_headers_on_each_request = true
  config.token_lifespan = 15.minutes
  config.token_cost = Rails.env.test? ? 4 : 10
  config.batch_request_buffer_throttle =  30.seconds
end
```

Please let me know, If I am doing anything wrong

Comment: Is something not working as you are hoping it would? Error messages or unexpected behavior?

Comment: @Eyeslandic, Yes I'm getting this error while I am continuously sending requests to the server and after this error my session/token is expired 
"authenticate_user!'
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected"
It should not be expired since I am continuously requesting the server. the server ought to be expired my session/token if I am not sending any request for 15 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate column, `last_accessed_at` which should be the `DateTime` field in the user's table.

Then, add the below snippet in the `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :validate_last_accessed


def validate_last_accessed
  if (current_user.last_accessed_at + 14.minutes) < DateTime.now
    current_user.tokens = {}
    current_user.save
    render json: {success: false, message: "your message in here"}
  else
    current_user.update(last_accessed_at: DateTime.now)
  end
end
```

There is no need for setting up token expiry to 15 minutes, you can even set it up to any number of days/weeks. The tokens will be cleared if the user is not accessing the application within the given time frame which is 15 minutes in this case.

**PRO TIP:** For the purpose of this feature, for every request you have to hit the database for updating the record. I would recommend you to use the cache database such as `redis` to store/update the user's last accessed time.

**Another Solution:** You can send the `current datetime` in every controller response, let the frontend takes care of the timeframe.

Comment: thank you so much, the solution worked for me. However, I would like to add one thing in the first if condition block, I added the 
current_user.last_accessed_at = nil
Since, whensoever, the user wants to login again the first if block always runs, thus the user can't log in, therefore I set current_user.last_accessed_at = nil

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you've set `token_lifespan` to 15 minutes (which DeviseTokenAuth understands as '15 minutes since last login'), but you actually want it to be `last_accessed_at + 15.minutes`. This isn't really what DeviseTokenAuth is designed to do, so you're going to need to write your own handlers for this.

You probably need a `before_action` that runs every time a request is received, which checks how long it's been since the last request, and invalidates the token if it's been more than 15 minutes. And you'll need a matching `after_action` filter that stores the time the user last accessed the application in the database (in a field like `last_accessed_at` similar to the automatic `created_at` field).

Comment: Thank you so much! So, the DeviseTokenAuth gem does not handle the extension of the token. I have to handle it by myself. right

Comment: That's my understanding - tokens usually have a fixed lifetime rather than a variable one. Indeed, AIUI the application can use DeviseTokenAuth to pass the expiry time to the client in a header so it can invalidate its own tokens!

Comment: Okay, crystal clear brother, you made my day